# TDD how to run multiple tests at once?

Tags: javascript

**What I am trying to do**

The program I'm following has me working on test driven development in JavaScript. It wants all the tests to complete at the same time. But my problem is that they're all required to be under the same function name sumAll. When two or more functions have the same name, this throws an error.

How do I run all tests at once without throwing an error? I can pass all the tests individually by deleting .skip off the next one and adding .skip to the previous one.

Here are the tests I am trying to run.

```js
const sumAll = require('./sumAll')

describe('sumAll', () => {
  test('sums numbers within the range', () => {
    expect(sumAll(1, 4)).toEqual(10);
  });
  test.skip('works with large numbers', () => {
    expect(sumAll(1, 4000)).toEqual(8002000);
  });
  test.skip('works with larger number first', () => {
    expect(sumAll(123, 1)).toEqual(7626);
  });
  test.skip('returns ERROR with negative numbers', () => {
    expect(sumAll(-10, 4)).toEqual('ERROR');
  });
  test.skip('returns ERROR with non-number parameters', () => {
    expect(sumAll(10, "90")).toEqual('ERROR');
  });
  test.skip('returns ERROR with non-number parameters', () => {
    expect(sumAll(10, [90, 1])).toEqual('ERROR');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the tag for the test framework you are using.

Comment: _It wants all the tests to complete at the same time._ What benefit does having all the tests complete at the same time provide?

Comment: @MetroSmurf I'm not sure why, I'm just a newbie in the javascript world, the program mentions specifically having them all complete at the same time though, from the exercise it reads "**All tests must pass at the same time**, and you should not have any `test.skip` instances by the time you finish an exercise"

Comment: Oh, that direction is saying: _The tests must all pass_. In other words, it is not asking to have all the tests complete at the same time, just to have them all pass during a single test run.

Comment: Removing all `.skip` should work (skip is only needed when you actually want to skip a test). Also rename your last test so that it's different from the one before it (eg replace "non-number" by "string" and "array")